# Some question of numerical polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne book "Algebraic geometry" Proposition I.7.3 (b),

Proposition I.7.3.(b) : If $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ is any function, and $Q$ is a numerical polynomial such that $\Delta f=f(n+1)-f(n)=Q(n)$ for all $n\gg 0$, then
there exists a numerical polynomial $P$ such that $f(n)=P(n)$ for all $n\gg 0$.

In proof of this proposition,
If $\Delta(f-P)=0 \text{ for } n\gg 0$, then $(f-P)(n)$ is constant for $n\gg 0$ and so
$f(n)=P(n)$ for $n\gg 0$.

But I can't understand this proof.
May be I see more in detail.?

Comment: You don't need to write $n>>0$.  You can write $n\gg 0$.  (I changed it.)

Comment: Should be $f(n) = P(n) + c$ for some constant $c$ in the last part of the statement.

Comment: Not having Hartshorne handy, I don't know 1. what $\Delta$ means, 2. what kind of things $f$ and $P$ are. Maybe you could edit this information into the body of the question.

Comment: Let $g: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ be any function.
If $\Delta(g)=0 \text{ for } n\gg 0$, then $g(n) = g(n+1) = g(n+2)=\cdots$ for $n\gg 0$.
So $g(n)$ is constant for $n\gg 0$.